# Empty array while uploading .3gp file in php

Tags: php

In my application i have file upload features where users can upload image and video files. I am able to upload all the files except .3gp. When i print in my back end i am getting empty array. File size which i am uploading is 10 MB and max upload in my php.ini is 20 MB. Below is my sample code which is working fine for other file extension.

Front End

```
   <form method="post" name="addAssets" action="/examengine/assets/addassets" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="upload" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile">
      <button type="submit" class="btn pri-btn">Upload</button>
   </form>
```

Backend

```
function addassets(){
    var_dump($_POST);
    var_dump($_FILES);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem Resolved

I changed post_max_size and resolved.